# How to get days of the week from jsonb array in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with jsonb array of datetime strings.
I want to find rows with a particular day of the week (say Tuesday).

```sql
create table my_table(id serial primary key, jsonb_col jsonb);
insert into my_table (jsonb_col) values
('["2022-10-05T18:00:00", "2022-10-07T18:00:00", "2022-11-05T18:00:00"]'),
('["2022-10-05T18:00:00",  "2023-10-05T18:00:00"]');
```

Here is a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/xtAVIfsn with this example

P.S. for the sake of this question let's ignore TZ

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this

```
select /*Number of day starting in 1*/
extract(isodow from jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_col)::varchar::date) 
from my_table mt;

select /*Name of day in plain text */
to_char(jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_col)::text::date, 'Day') 
from my_table mt;
```

Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/AhTCEZRG

Comment: Thanks, Pepe! I came to same conclusions :)